# PHP not checking script file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php file that contains a javascript object (which is in part echoed by php). That file is called by:

```
<script src="js/file.php"></script>
```

The contents of the file are basically:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
$custom_icons = JSON_encode($object);
?>

var JSON_icons = <?php echo $custom_icons ?>;


var icons = JSON_icons + {
    "facebook": {'name': 'facebook', 'text': 'Facebook', 'icon_url': 'img/logos/facebook.png', 'url': 'http://www.facebook.com'}
};
```

Please ignore any coding / syntax errors that might appear due to the shortening of the script. The problem I'm having is that when the script is called, javascript throws the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Which basically means php didn't go through the file and print what it should. It basically left the file untouched and the php code remained there.

How can I solve this? I'm really lost here.

Thank you!

**UPDATE:** PHP actually checked the file, found some errors, and consequentially echoed them using html elements. The invalid '<' token comes from a `<br/>` printed by php and not from the `<?php` tag itself, like I (dumbly) thought.

Comment: Try `var JSON_icons = '<?php echo $custom_icons ?>';`

Comment: What is the actual output of the file.php?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran json_encode produces a string to valid object syntax `{"a":1, "b":2}` so if you put quotes around the object you're making it a string so would need to parse it `var JSON_icons = JSON.parse('<?php echo $custom_icons ?>');` which is pointless –

Comment: Please show the **generated output** too.

Comment: My guess is the generated PHP has some errors, warnings or notices inside. They are rendered as HTML in the output if you have `error_reporting` on. Check the resulting PHP and make sure that's legal JavaScript.

Comment: I answered the question myself. Thanks to everyone, especially to the ones who advised to check the output of the file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Problem is this:

```
var icons = JSON_icons + {
    "facebook": {'name': 'facebook', 'text': 'Facebook', 'icon_url': 'img/logos/facebook.png', 'url': 'http://www.facebook.com'}
};
```

Because `JSON_encode($object)` results in a string beginning with `{` and ending with `}` your result in concatinating `... JSON_icons + { ...` results in `... }{ ...` which causes the unexpected token error.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, my bad. PHP does check the file. The invalid token is actually part of an error message printed by php. Here is what the file.php looks like if accessed through the browser:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: icons in <b>C:\...\js\file.php</b> on line <b>42</b><br />

var JSON_icons = null;

...

var icons = custom_icons + {
    "facebook": {'name': 'facebook', 'text': 'Facebook', 'icon_url': 'img/logos/facebook.png', 'url': 'http://www.facebook.com'}, ...
};
```

P.S: Thanks, @Sbls